# Why do we use a CMOS for inverting a circuit when the PMOS already achieves that?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, cmos, nmos, pmos

The output in a PMOS is as follows:

```
I/P    O/P  
 0      1  
 1      0
```

Why can't I just use this instead of using a CMOS for inverting logic?
(Please explain in simple terms as I am a beginner in this topic and subject)

Comment: FWIW, what OP describes is not a characteristic of PMOS transistors, but of common source/common emitter stages.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a word: **Efficiency**.

---

You can use a PMOS transistor to drive a logic output high (e.g. VDD) when the input is low (e.g. GND). However, you **can't use that same PMOS transistor to drive a logic output low when the input is high**.

When you drive the input high in your PMOS inverter, **it turns off**, leaving the output effectively high-impedance, **which is not logic low**.

Your actual truth table is:

```
I/P    O/P

 0      1
 1      Z
```

You can overcome this inability to drive low, by using a resistor to pull the output low when the transistor is off. However to be able to strongly drive low, you need a **low value resistor**.

[image]

This resistor is always across the output, which means that when you turn the PMOS on to drive high, a large current will flow from the PMOS through the resistor to ground. **This uses lots of energy**. If you have billions of switches, you can see that the **power consumption will be very high**.

The better approach is to replace this resistor with an NMOS transistor. This is called CMOS. By using a **NMOS** device, you can think of it as being **able turn off the resistor** when the output is driven high (PMOS is on).

Using the NMOS you can also get a **strong logic low** because when switched on, the NMOS is effectively a short.

CMOS therefore by using complementary transistors, has **very low static power dissipation** - when an output is being held either high or low, almost no power is consumed.

Answer (score 8):

CMOS, while more complex to make, [consumes very little power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS#Power:_switching_and_leakage) when not switching, while PMOS consumes more power even when it's not switching.

From [here,](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece110/fa2018/content/courseNotes/files/?logicAndCMOS) be the circuit below for a simple inverter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTK7MF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When IN = 0, then the NMOS (M2) is (almost) an open-circuit and the PMOS (M1) is (almost) a short-circuit. The opposite for when IN = 1: the NMOS is a short-circuit and the PMOS is a open-circuit. It's either Vdd (5V) or ground at the output which is being driven "strongly".

As a result you have lower power dissipation.

Comment: CMOS may actually be easier to make, considering the fact that IC resistors are physically much larger than MOSFETs.